# Dynamically add & remove rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 different table in same page. 2 table having functionality that dynamically add & remove rows.

When i remove dynamically added row from 2nd table it affects table 1.

`sr. no` column in 2nd table, when i remove row from 2nd table it shows the `sr. nos` in 1st table. But there is no sr no column in table first.

```
$(document).on('click', '.del', function() {
    var index = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    for(var i=index; i<$('table tbody tr').children().length; i++){

        $('table tbody tr:nth-child(' + i + ') td:first-child').text(i);
    }
    // more code in fiddle
 });
```

[see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/26uuw779/)

Comment: Clicking the delete button in table 2 not only deletes the order line item in table 2, but also assigns numbers to column 1 of table 1.  What is the expected behavior and what is the problem?

Comment: I'd _strongly_ encourage you not to use `$(this).parent().parent()`.... to navigate the DOM.  Instead, learn to use `$(this).closest('tr');`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code

```
$('#potable tbody tr:nth-child(' + i + ') td:first-child').text(i); //change
```

Instead of below

```
$('table tbody tr:nth-child(' + i + ') td:first-child').text(i);
```

Reason why your code was not working is because you are relying on selector 'table'   and for both the table it is true and you are checking first child so its affecting first child i.e child of first table,  If you rely on specific ID '#potable' it will affect only second table nth-child(x) will bring xth child of second table.